# How I can split and sort this data set

Tags: r

Here is a small sample size of my data:

```
var         colour no Mcolour Ncolour
sa1_fr_19   B      10 66      3
sa1_fr_19   W      12 85      6
su3_sa2_18  B      8  70      9
su3_sa2_18  W      6  24      1
```

I want to get this table:

```
year var sort nB McolourB NcolourB nW McolourW NcolourW
19   sa1 fr   10 66       3        12 85       6
18   su3 sa2  8  70       9        6  24       1
```

It would be good if we could do it using base R codes

Answer (score 2):

Split the columns on `'_'` and use `pivot_wider`.

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(var, c('var', 'sort', 'year'), sep = '_') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = colour, values_from = c(no, Mcolour, Ncolour), names_sep = '')

#  var   sort  year    noB   noW McolourB McolourW NcolourB NcolourW
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
#1 sa1   fr    19       10    12       66       85        3        6
#2 su3   sa2   18        8     6       70       24        9        1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(var = c("sa1_fr_19", "sa1_fr_19", "su3_sa2_18", 
"su3_sa2_18"), colour = c("B", "W", "B", "W"), no = c(10L, 12L, 
8L, 6L), Mcolour = c(66L, 85L, 70L, 24L), Ncolour = c(3L, 6L, 
9L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks, can we do it without library(magrittr), especially r base codes?

Comment: I've done the `base R` task partially: this works for the first two variables you want to have: `df$var1 <- sub("^([^_]+)(?=_).*", "\\1", df$var, perl = TRUE)
df$sort <- sub(".*(?<=_)([^_]+)(?=_).*", "\\1", df$var, perl = TRUE)`. Maybe you can proceed in this manner for the other variables.

Comment: Thank you. I have just copied your codes, but I got the error: unexpected symbol in ...

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
dcast(cSplit(df, "var", sep="_"), var_1 + var_2 + var_3  ~ colour,
    value.var = c("no", "Mcolour", "Ncolour"))
   var_1 var_2 var_3 no_B no_W Mcolour_B Mcolour_W Ncolour_B Ncolour_W
1:   sa1    fr    19   10   12        66        85         3         6
2:   su3   sa2    18    8    6        70        24         9         1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(var = c("sa1_fr_19", "sa1_fr_19", "su3_sa2_18", 
"su3_sa2_18"), colour = c("B", "W", "B", "W"), no = c(10L, 12L, 
8L, 6L), Mcolour = c(66L, 85L, 70L, 24L), Ncolour = c(3L, 6L, 
9L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```